# Replica is stuck waiting for

Tags: postgresql, replication

Running two PostgreSQL 9.2.3 instances.  One is master and other is slave.

All was working for awhile, I could make changes on master and see them on the slave but now my slave is not getting changes any more.

```
1000     25069  0.2  0.1 131616 11280 pts/0    S    01:02   0:00 /usr/local/pgsql/bin/postmaster -D /mnt/pgdb/v9.2.3 -i
1000     25074  0.0  0.0 131724  1440 ?        Ss   01:02   0:00 postgres: startup process   waiting for 000000040000000700000083
```

I've tried countless things including completely blowing away the slave, running *initdb* and *rsync*ing the master back to the slave, launching the slave only to find it still stuck in this same dam state.

What the hell am I doing wrong here?

Slave's *recovery.conf* looks as follows:

```
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'host=172.16.0.14'
trigger_file = '/tmp/pgfailover'
restore_command = 'cd .'
```

I've also tried the following on the master to no avail:

```
$PGDIR/psql -U $UNAME -d postgres -c "select pg_start_backup('clone',true);"
rsync -av --exclude pg_xlog --exclude postgresql.conf /mnt/pgdb/current/* 172.16.0.8:/mnt/pgdb/current/
$PGDIR/psql -U $UNAME -d postgres -c "select pg_stop_backup();"
```

UPDATE - Including relevant information pertaining to replicate problem.

postgresql.conf on the Master node

```
wal_level = hot_standby
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'cd .'

max_wal_senders = 3
wal_keep_segments = 5000
hot_standby = on
hot_standby_feedback = on
```

The Slave Node's postgresql.conf has these settings:

```
wal_level = hot_standby
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'cd .'

max_wal_senders = 3
hot_standby = on
hot_standby_feedback = on
```

Comment: Are the WAL files generated while copying the data files to the new slave still available to the new slave at the time of the startup attempt?  I. e. do you have WAL archiving set up or a replication slot defined?

Comment: I think WAL archiving is setup OK.  I updated my post to reflect more of those settings.  Keep in mind this was working at one point and now seems stuck.  I don't know what you mean by a "replication slot defined".  Are you referring to select pg_start_backup/select pg_stop_backup?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, `cd .` does not really archive anything - it keeps the files in place, and those are only accessible to the slave if it can reach this filesystem (which is not really usual, I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the standby doesn't successfully connect to the master.

In order to be able to use the streaming replication, the master needs to have enough WALs in the streaming buffer that it can send to the standby. 
Since you're not using log shipping, it needs to store all the logs from when you started the backup to when the standby has been started.

You can control the number of WAL's stored in the buffer by setting `wal_keep_segments` to a high enough value.

You should also make sure that `max_wal_senders` is set to the number of standby servers you have.

However, it is always best to have the WAL restore set as a backup for when the streaming replication doesn't work for any reason. You can achieve that by setting the `archive_command` in `postgresql.conf` and the `restore_command` in `recovery.conf`

For instance like this, assuming that `/pgsql/backups/archive_logs` is mounted as a nfs share accessible on both servers:

```
archive_command = 'cp %p /pgsql/backups/archive_logs/%f'
restore_command = 'cp /pgsql/backups/archive_logs/%f %p'
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help.  I updated my original post to give more information.  wal_keep_segments = 5000.  The archive_command and restore_command are both 'cd .' and there is no NFS here.  The two nodes each have local disk storage they are using and they can connect to each other.  I can run psql from one and connect to the other no problem.  This was all working at one point in time and now seems stuck.  So the settings I've posted at least were OK for some time.  I'm confused as to why I need an archive_command that copies WAL segments if we are streaming copies?

Comment: Update: Accepting your answer since it lead me to the root cause.  Somehow the pg_hba.conf was the same on both servers thus preventing the replica from connecting to the master.  Once I corrected that, everything is working again.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: Right, that would of course have been the first thing to check if it can't connect. I missed that :) As for why you need an archive_command. It's not needed, but a good to have fallback if the streaming would fail. It would never be used as long as the streaming replication is running.